# App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection - IOS 9

Tags: ios, connection

I'm facing problem connection to API with using IP address. 
Even I had add the following code to plist, it still show error as below:

"http://xx3.xx.xx8.xx7/xxx/xxx/ error: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."

This is the code I add to the plist

```
     <key>xx3.xx.xx8.xx7</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </key>
```

Answer (score 19):

Document [Allowing Insecure Connection to a Single Server here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html). So you must add `NSAppTransportSecurity` to your info.plist file in truth way like flowing (to show Info.plist in source, in Xcode right click to Info.plist "Open As"->"Source Code")

**To configure a per-domain exception:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <!--others key-->
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>insecure-domain1.example.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            </dict>
            <key>insecure-domain2.example.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <!--others key-->
</dict>
</plist>
```

after edit Infor.plist file look like following: 
[image]

**Or disable ATS:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

after edit Infor.plist file look like following: 
[image]

Comment: Yes, I had place inside NSAppTransportSecurity. But still received same error: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.

Comment: it's not true because if you add NSAppTransportSecurity to your main info plist file. all connection to this domain will allow run in non secure mode

Comment: I just put what exactly your code to plist. But still receive same error

Comment: try disable ATS in second way. and check plist file is really Info.plist File setting in your "target" -> "Build Settings"

Comment: So means ATS only work for domain, but not work for IP?

Comment: @user831098 It's correct that Exception Domains in ATS only works with named domains at this time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034645/nsallowsarbitraryloads-not-working-for-ip-address/33297898#33297898.

Comment: your_domain_name examples pls?

Comment: @voghDev you can see in Image example: stackoverflow.com

Comment: And if you want to do exactly that but in an Watch App (Watchkit)? On the "info.plist" of the Watch App you can not specify (Allow Arbitrary Loads). And even if you specify on the Watch App Extension, it does not work. PLEASE, SOME HELP?

Answer (score 9):

**Simple & Easiest Solution just in 3 Steps**

[image]

*Add the following two properties & run again... happy coding :-)*

[image]