# XCODE swift - webview can't open ics link - in safari it works

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, webview

I've made in Swift a webview & in that webview there are links to ics file on the same domain of the webview. Now, when you click this link in Safari, you can perfectly add this to your calendar, but when I try this in iOS simulator, or on my device, I can't 'open' the ICS file link.
Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!
This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webAgenda: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var activityagenda: UIActivityIndicatorView!

var url = "http://******.be/agenda.php"

func loadURL () {
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    webAgenda.loadRequest(request)

    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadURL()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    activityagenda.hidden = false
    activityagenda.startAnimating()

    }

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    activityagenda.hidden = true
    activityagenda.stopAnimating()


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

because you load a http site so in iOS9 will have problem with App Transport Security.

disable ATS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712155/app-transport-security-policy-requires-the-use-of-a-secure-connection-ios-9/32712420#32712420)

Comment: Hi, already implemented disable ATS in the info.plist like on your link... What else could be the issue?

Comment: Maybe can I configure that these links are opened in Safari?

Comment: @Cedric__ add webView:didFailLoadWithError: delegate to check if error occur. Make sure your web view frame now is correct